# angularjs ngmodel value with two values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope

I have this dropdown control

```
<div ng-repeat="prop in props" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Property {{$index + 1}} ({{prop.Value}})</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <select ng-model="gradingvalues[$index]" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And in the js code the gradingvalues array is declared as:

```
$scope.gradingvalues = [];
```

What I want is, beside the actual value which is selected in the dropdown, I want to have the propertyID as well, something like:

```
ng-model="gradingvalues[$index, propertyID]"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: is `propertyID` a property of `prop`? is `gradingValues` an array?

Comment: yes for both questions

Comment: Make `ng-model` an object with two properties...?

Comment: You ve a gradingvalue exactly for every prop so why don't use prop.gradingvalue as ng-model??

Comment: @Vanojx your advice helped me, can you make that answer pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props and gradingvalues will be always in a 1:1 relation so you can use a property of "prop" to store the grading values:

```
<div ng-repeat="prop in props" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Property {{$index + 1}}    ({{prop.Value}})</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <select ng-model="prop.gradingvalue" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$scope.gradingvalues = [];` instead of an array use an object:

```
$scope.gradingvalues = {};
```

And update your `ng-model`

```
ng-model="gradingvalues[prop]"
```

This way you will have the "`propertyID`" as a key with the value selected on the select element.

Comment: Thanks @taguenizy prop is whole object and when I use your answer I'm getting one value for all the properties, this is the prop object https://i.gyazo.com/b7d8fefeb9d11fc66ca9b15c2ad48a88.png

Comment: @Laziale from that object you just want the `propertyID`? And is that a unique value across the objects? And your `props` is an array of objects?